# Can't copy text generated in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

All I'm trying to do is copy the text that I generate in the js file when the copy button is clicked. I keep getting an error that it can't recognize the "$" but it looks like a loaded jquery? (Yes the jquery files are attached in the folder). This is the error I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

manifest.json

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "clipboardWrite", // for copy and cut
        "clipboardRead", // for paste

        ],
     "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery-git2.js", 
                "jquery.zclip.min.js",
                "feed.js"],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
      }]
}
```

extension.html

```
<body>

<p id = "sharelink"> Share this link to make a payment </p>    

<div id = "description"></div>


<a href="#" id="copy"><div id = "copybutton">Copy</div></a> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="feed.js"></script>
</body>
```

feed.js

```
  function createNumber() { 
   var roomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 999999
    var base = "http://groupmoney.com/making?="

    var urlfinal = base + roomNumber;

    var td1 = document.getElementById('description');
    var text = document.createTextNode(urlfinal);
    td1.appendChild(text);
  }
  createNumber();

$("#copy").click(function () {
    $('#copy').zclip({
        path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('#description').text(),
        beforeCopy: function () {
            $('#description').css('background', 'yellow');
        },
        afterCopy: function () {
            $('#description').css('background', 'green');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not entirely sure if the copy to clipboard thing even works since it's flash on an extension. Any idea on how I can fix that? <- I think that's the bigger question.

Comment: Well that's because you're using ZeroClipboard, which uses the Flash clipboard APIs instead of the Chrome extension ones.

Comment: Ohh. Can you please suggest how I can fix it? Thank you!!!

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have much experience with Chrome APIs. Instead I point you towards the [API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

Comment: There are no specific APIs to work with clipboard (anymore) in Chrome. One needs to do `document.execCommand('copy')` and friends.